# How to make compiler check what's given to SIGNAL()?

Tags: qt, macros, syntax-error

In writing a Qt4 app, I clumsily wrote:

```
QObject::connect(spinbox, SIGNAL(vlaueChanged(int)), ....
```

and it compiled, and it ran, but of course the spinbox didn't have any effect.

Such misspellings should be caught. I always assumed that valueChanged() was declared in some header file, but apparently not.  Any arbitrary garbage can be given to SIGNAL() or SLOT(), and it'll compile.  My toy program is small. For a huge app with dynamically created controls connected on the fly, an error like this could be very hard to track down.

Is there some way to do error checking for this kind of typo?  Is it possible for the compiler (gcc) to do this, or is some other tool appropriate?

Comment: It's not very hard to track down if you read the application output.

Answer (score 1):

This has been changed for Qt5. You can read about it [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Answer (score 0):

`SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros turn their arguments into strings, and they are not checked in compile time (because... they are string actually). In case of wrong signal/slot name `Qt` writes warning (`qWarn`) in runtime. They say, in Qt5 something changed there.

In my experience, sometimes you really can do such a mistake (though rarely, autocompletion helps a lot), but it can be easily tracked down and fixed.